# VHDL: Which Ethernet data are seen by wireshark?

Tags: ethernet

- I want to send data to wireshark.
  [image]
- I was able to receive data FROM wireshark at my device
- I already can send it to a similar device I use and I can see my data "easily" (<--  xD)
- I just want to see the raw data in wireshark !
- I tried to setup promiscuous mode

  - in wireshark ( its there by default)
  - by ubuntu command like `ip link set eth1 promisc on`
- I don't know if I send them in the
  right order
- But it shouldn't be a problem if I only want to see raw data!
- I generate XGMII in a loop.
- It is 64 bit parallel and enters a
  XAUI-core.
- It should translate it into XAUI and send then to my
  computer.
- the PC LED begins to **blink** directly if I want to send
- wireshark shows some weird data but I think they **don't** belong to my generated data because they have some text in it like : "HP-computer 123 "!

I want to see the raw data on my pc.

I tried it with different patterns but I cant see it.
This is one of different tests I have written.

**One important thing I didn't tested is to check if by changing some transceiver polarities it may work!**

```
    ---case  , und in jedem case +1
        if rising_edge(refclk_out_xaui_o) then
                IF counter_frame_send = 0 THEN
                  xgmii_txd_i <= X"d5555555555555fb"; -- 7 Byte preamble 
                  xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"01";
                ELSIF counter_frame_send = 1 THEN
                  xgmii_txd_i <= X"12DA649D99B1964A";
                  xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"00";
                ELSIF counter_frame_send = 2 THEN
                  xgmii_txd_i <= X"55AA2E0006050403";
                  xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"00";
                ELSIF counter_frame_send >= 3 and counter_frame_send <= 7 THEN
                  xgmii_txd_i <= X"55AA55AAAA55AA55";
                  xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"00";
                
                ELSIF counter_frame_send = 8 THEN
                  xgmii_txd_i <= X"70CB2707AA55AA55";
                  xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"00";
                ELSIF counter_frame_send = 9 THEN
                  --counter_frame_send <= "0000000"; --reset
                  xgmii_txd_i(63 DOWNTO 0) <= X"07070707070707fd"; ---FRAME END
                  xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"FF";
                ELSE
                ---  send idle...
                      xgmii_txd_i(63 DOWNTO 0) <= X"0707070707070707"; ---FRAME END
                      xgmii_txc_i(7 DOWNTO 0) <= X"FF";
                END IF;
             counter_frame_send <= counter_frame_send + 1;

             else
             -- noting
             end if;
```

On the FPGA it looks like this order:

[image: ila core]

My wireshark doesn't get any of this kind of message I think !
I wonder if I am sending it right or if I should reorder it:

Comment: Are you sure data is sent on the wire? Does your switch has any indicator for transmission?

Comment: You'll have to use an etherprobe or something in that class, there are too many reasons this may not work with standard switches and network cards.

Comment: hmm interesting :)  .. ah it is a selfmade device. and my led @ pc reacts to it. my other device also can receive some data from--- it think xD

Comment: I still see nothing of my send data. I checked the promiscuous mode. In wireshark it is even setup by default xD

Comment: damn I read in a book that even with sudo an promiscuous mode not all data are passed to the upper layer of linux. So my frame needs to be correct